# ¿Algún ejemplo de cómo capturar fotos e incluirlas directamente a una base de datos local con GreenDAO?

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos

Pues eso, he mirado muchísimos ejemplos pero todos vienen con SQLite y me gustaría implementar algún ejemplo con GreenDAO para tomar fotos desde el móvil y pasarlas directamente a la base de datos que se encuentra en la memoria externa. He comenzado un proyecto nuevo y he leído la documentación para integrar así todos los componentes necesarios para que todo funcione. ¿Alguna sugerencia, idea o página donde se explique esto con más detalle? Estoy harto de buscar esto mismo para GreenDAO y no encuentro casi nada.

Comment: Tu pregunta está muy amplia, es como preguntar como hacer un automóvil :s. Te sugiero que dividas tu pregunta en partes, primero sería como crear bd's usando la librería GreenDao, después como hacer las CRUD'S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomar una foto no lo puedes hacer con GreenDao,

Sin embargo, si ya tienes la foto guardada y sabes la ubicación donde esta, guarda la ubicación en GreenDao, y con la ubicación en mano puedes cargar la foto en Cualquier ImageView.

Te recomendaría que guardes mejor el dataString de la foto en vez de la ubicación, ya que si te borran la foto de la ubicación, no te la cargaría, pero si tienes el datastring guardado, persistiria.

Sobre el ejemplo de captura de fotos:

Puedes usar el siguiente codigo como ejemplo,

```
 package test.helper.tomafoto;
02 import java.io.File;
03 import java.io.IOException;
04 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
05 import java.util.Date;
06 
07 import android.net.Uri;
08 import android.os.Bundle;
09 import android.os.Environment;
10 import android.provider.MediaStore;
11 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
12 import android.app.Activity;
13 import android.content.Intent;
14 import android.util.Log;
15 import android.view.Menu;
16 import android.view.View;
17 import android.widget.Button;
18 
19 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
20  //Aqui defines la ruta de donde se guardaran las fotos.
21  private final String ruta_fotos = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/misfotos/";
22     private File file = new File(ruta_fotos);
23     private Button boton;
24     
25  @Override
26  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
27   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
28   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
29  
30   boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTomaFoto);
31  
32   file.mkdirs();
33   
34   boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
35 
36    @Override
37    public void onClick(View v) {
38     String file = ruta_fotos + getCode() + ".jpg";
39     File mi_foto = new File( file );
40     try {
41                  mi_foto.createNewFile();
42              } catch (IOException ex) {              
43               Log.e("ERROR ", "Error:" + ex);
44              }       
45              //
46              Uri uri = Uri.fromFile( mi_foto );
47              //Abre la camara para tomar la foto
48              Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
49              //Guarda imagen
50              cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
51              //Retorna a la actividad
52              startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
53    }
54 
55   });
56  
57  }
58 
59  
60  
61  
62 
63  @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
64  private String getCode()
65  {
66   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
67   String date = dateFormat.format(new Date() );
68   String photoCode = "pic_" + date;  
69   return photoCode;
70  }
71  
72  @Override
73  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
74   
75   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
76   return true;
77  }
78 
79 }
```

Adicionalmente debes poner en el manifest, el permiso para utilizar la camara.

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación, algo así es lo que estoy buscando.

Comment: Actualice la respuesta con el ejemplo de toma de fotos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu aportación! me ha servido este código!